# React Native Webview OnLoad called twice

Tags: react-native, webview, onload-event

React native webview onLoad(), onLoadStart(), onLoadEnd() all called twice

Find my code below

```js
<WebView
  source={{
    uri,
  }}
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
  ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
  startInLoadingState
  style={{ marginTop: 0, flex: 1 }}
  renderLoading={() => this.displaySpinner()}
  javaScriptEnabled
  geolocationEnabled
  injectedJavaScript={setTimeoutInjection}
  onLoad={() => this.pageLoadEnd(renderTime)}
  onLoadStart={() => {
    Alert.alert('On load event', `Loading time : ${Date.now() - renderTime}`)
  }}
  onLoadEnd={() => {
    Alert.alert('On load event End', `Loading time : ${Date.now() - renderTime}`)
  }}
  sharedCookiesEnabled
  useWebKit
  onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

What should I change so that onload() events are called only once?

Comment: Can you share `setTimeoutInjection` and `pageLoadEnd`

Comment: What does a function do in your code?

Comment: @aytek    Please find out the code for setTimeoutInjection below  and pageLoadEnd injectsJS after page is loaded.               const setTimeoutInjection = `setTimeout(function(){RCI.postLogin.handleSessionExpirationWarningResponse = function(response){
    }; true;},0)`;

Comment: @hongdeveloper what do you mean?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide additional information there. You need to share all  the codes of your component so that we can understand the problem.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually **set a flag** after first `onLoad` call.

```js
  const wasLoaded = useRef(false);

  const handleWebViewLoaded = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!wasLoaded.current) {
       // do something once...       

       wasLoaded.current = true;
    }
  }, []);

  <WebView
    onLoad={handleWebViewLoaded}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and it turned out be a simple missing "/" at the end of the uri in the source property.